# In a standard metric space....what does | | mean (is it the absolute value or something more)?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

We have a standard metric space defined as:

($\mathbb{R}$,d)= ($\mathbb{R}$, | |)

$d(x,y)=|x-y|$

Does | | in first sentence always mean that we must do $|x-y|$; so that we look only at the distance between variables in the case if we had only ($\mathbb{R}$,d)= ($\mathbb{R}$, | |)?

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to typeset common math expressions with MathJax, and [see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to use Markdown formatting. By R, do you mean $\mathbb{R}$ (which is obtained via `$\mathbb{R}$`)?

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the letter now.

Comment: I think yes.It is a norm in 2 dimensional space.

Answer (score 2):

In the context you've presented, $|\;\;|$ does denote the absolute value function on the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$. By writing the bars without an argument, it is a (very slight) abuse of notation; it is analogous to how we can refer to a function $f$ without specifying any input value of the function, like with the expression $f(x_0)$.

A metric space, speaking precisely, is a pair of things:

1. A set $M$.
2. A function $d$, from the set $M\times M$ to the set $\mathbb{R}$, satisfying [various properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Definition).

In the text you're asking about, the author is describing the usual way of putting a metric on $\mathbb{R}$, by defining the function
$$d(x,y)=|x-y|$$
where $|\;\;|$, again, is the absolute value.

Comment: Okey..so if this abuse of notation appears, || means |x−y| ?

Comment: No, it means the function that inputs a real number and outputs its absolute value. Think of it like this: we can decide to name the "absolute value function $\mathrm{abs}$. It is a function that inputs real numbers and outputs real numbers,
$$\mathrm{abs}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},$$
according to the rule $\mathrm{abs}(t)=|t|$. Now, instead of coming up with a name like $\mathrm{abs}$, we just use the bars $|\;\;|$ without anything inside them. We would write
$$|\;\;|:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$$
instead.

Comment: oh, okey, thank you :)

Comment: @urska: If my answer is satisfactory, you can accept it: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer